# how to select a record from multiple tables

Tags: t-sql

I'd be glad if someone could show me how I can select a record from 12 tables.

The main issue is that I have a table for each subject for storing marks obtained by students.

Each subject table has the following columns: StudentId, RegId, AcademicYear, Term, Form, ClassScore, ExamScore, Total, Grade.

The `studentDetails.Students` table which contains students demographic record has `StudentId`  column as its primary key.

Comment: This is a pretty elementary task with SQL. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use Union, It's very simple

Comment: Using UNION returns something closer to what I want but the problem now is that I have to include **photo** from Students table and **Program of study** from Registration table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways that you can return the data.

You can use a `JOIN` between the `students` table and all of the `subjects` tables:

```
select *  -- replace this with the columns you want to return
from Students s
left join subject1 s1
    on s.studentid = s1.studentid
left join subject2 s2
    on s.studentid = s2.studentid
left join subject3 s3
    on s.studentid = s3.studentid
left join subject4 s4
    on s.studentid = s4.studentid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17489/7)

Or you can use something like the following which joins the `students` table with a subquery that uses a `UNION ALL` between each `subject` table:

```
select s.StudentId, S.StudentName, S.Photo,
   sb.StudentId, sb.RegId, sb.AcademicYear, 
   sb.Term, sb.Form, sb.ClassScore, sb.ExamScore, sb.Total, sb.Grade
from students s
inner join
(
    select s1.StudentId, s1.RegId, s1.AcademicYear, 
          s1.Term, s1.Form, s1.ClassScore, s1.ExamScore, s1.Total, s1.Grade, 
          'Subject1' as src
    from subject1 s1
    union all
    select s2.StudentId, s2.RegId, s2.AcademicYear, 
          s2.Term, s2.Form, s2.ClassScore, s2.ExamScore, s2.Total, s2.Grade, 
          'Subject2' as src
    from subject2 s2
    union all
    select s3.StudentId, s3.RegId, s3.AcademicYear, 
          s3.Term, s3.Form, s3.ClassScore, s3.ExamScore, s3.Total, s3.Grade, 
          'Subject3' as src
    from subject3 s3
) sb
    on s.studentid = sb.studentid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17489/5)

If you have another table that you want to join, then you will use:

```
select s.StudentId, S.StudentName, S.Photo,
   sb.StudentId, sb.RegId, sb.AcademicYear, 
   sb.Term, sb.Form, sb.ClassScore, sb.ExamScore, sb.Total, sb.Grade,
   r.programofstudy
from students s
inner join
(
    select s1.StudentId, s1.RegId, s1.AcademicYear, 
          s1.Term, s1.Form, s1.ClassScore, s1.ExamScore, s1.Total, s1.Grade, 
          'Subject1' as src
    from subject1 s1
    union all
    select s2.StudentId, s2.RegId, s2.AcademicYear, 
          s2.Term, s2.Form, s2.ClassScore, s2.ExamScore, s2.Total, s2.Grade, 
          'Subject2' as src
    from subject2 s2
    union all
    select s3.StudentId, s3.RegId, s3.AcademicYear, 
          s3.Term, s3.Form, s3.ClassScore, s3.ExamScore, s3.Total, s3.Grade, 
          'Subject3' as src
    from subject3 s3
) sb
    on s.studentid = sb.studentid
left join Registration r
    on s.studentid = r.studentid 
    and sb.regid = r.regid
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Sir. I'm trying it and I'd give you a feedback soon.

Comment: Both of your answers return the following results:

Comment: Both of your answers return the following results: **StudentId, StudentName and Photo** but I want the query to return AcademicYear, Term,Form,Class,Exam,Total,Grade,Rank,Roll as well. I tried using **Union** and got everything excluding StudentId,StudentName and Photo from the Students table.

Comment: @Akaglo see my edit and a demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17489/5

Comment: Pls I don't quite get you. This is what I did. `select s.StudentId, s.StudentName,s.Photo
from StudentDetails.Students s
left join ProgramDetails.EnglishLanguage s1
    on s.studentid = s1.studentid
left join ProgramDetails.Mathematics s2
    on s.studentid = s2.studentid
left join ProgramDetails.IntegratedScience s3
    on s.studentid = s3.studentid
left join ProgramDetails.SocialStudies s4
    on s.studentid = s4.studentid`

Comment: @Akaglo in your sample, you have to include in the select statement the columns from the `s1.*` See this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17489/7

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind assistance. Everything is now working well based on what I asked you, but I wish to add **ProgramOfStudy** column from the Registration table which also has StudentId and RegId columns. How do I go about it, Sir?

Comment: @Akaglo you will add a `left join Registration on s.studentid = r.studentid and sb.regid = r.regid`. Then in your select statement you will add `r.programofstudy`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25101/discussion-between-akaglo-and-bluefeet)

Answer (score 1):

An example using a union query:

```
SELECT au_lname FROM authors
UNION ALL
SELECT lname FROM Employee
ORDER BY au_lname
```